# Can't reset TextArea length

Tags: textarea, javafx-2

I print socket output to textArea (it's in Service object), but after a while, my textArea gets filled and gives me exceptions, so I tried resetting it with textArea.setText(""); but textArea.getLength() doesn't reset to 0. Here's my code:

```
if(textArea.getLength() > 1000)
   textArea.setText(""); // problem!
command = in.getText(); //command to sent to socket
out.println(command);
textField.setText(""); // just resetting textField (works)
```

Thanks!

Comment: _"textArea.getLength() doesn't reset to 0."_ That wouldn't make much sense. Could you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, now I see how one could understand that. I wanted to say that when I check value of text.Area.getLength() (e.g. printing the value on System.out), I don't get 0 after textArea.setText(""). It just keeps counting new bytes without resetting to 0.

Comment: `textArea.setText("")` is working fine. Show the exception stack trace. Also provide your JavaFX version.

Comment: Hmm, I've re-checked. It does reset the length to 0, and empty the area so it can write again BUT it seems that textArea has small capacity, so sometimes it happens that if it's at, let's say, 80% full and it receives large amount of data, it will go out of bounds and throw exception.
Stack trace is too long to post it here and doesn't mention my code lines in it. If you want, I can break it in small parts and post.

Comment: @user2510434. Use "@" + "user_name" (like at the beginning) when commenting to a particular person. The related person will be notified. Otherwise not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting textArea length JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325833/resetting-textarea-length-javafx)