# Resetting textArea length JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I wrote server in C and client in Java. I used JavaFX for GUI. Everything works except that sometimes I get exceptions when textArea gets filled and receives more data before it gets reseted (probably cause of parallel threading). Actually there are 3 cases which occur "randomly":
1) Stucks/hangs and no exceptions are thrown.
2) NullPointerException (about Line Padding and Content Bounds [there's nowhere my code mentioned]).
3) IllegalArgumentException: Both width and height must be >= 0.
4) Exception about String text bounds.

Here's the code if it helps:

```
if(textArea.getLength() > 500) // I tried with > 2000, similar situations occur
    textArea.setText("");
command = textField.getText();
out.println(command); // out to socket
textField.setText("");
```

Btw, this GUI should represent basic Linux shell, so textArea should sometimes be able to receive large amount of data (such as netstat command).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an exact dublicate of your previous question but with more info, so not going to vote for closing. I asked you to post exception stacktrace in that previous question, but you mentioned there is no your code related lines in stacktrace, hence I also presume like you that it is a bug of textArea. So I suggest to try to use another component, for example a big Label with white background :), if it is solely for displaying purposes.

Comment: I thought you forgot about me so I made another question cause I really need to do this. I'll try to do with label, haha would never thought of that :D Thanks!

Comment: :It seems that Label doesn't have .appendText() method and I don't know why I can't pass the Label reference to my Service. Anyway, if I could, I can only .setText() to label which isn't very nice solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user2510434. try `label.setText(label.getText() + " appending a text");`